# Combination of elements of lists that meet some condition?

Tags: list, numpy, tuples

Given:

```
a = [5, 2, 8, 3, 9]

b = [3, 5, 7, 6, 8]

c = [8, 5, 7, 4, 9].
```

What is needed:

`d = [(9, 8), (8, 7), ..., (5, 5, 5), (5, 6, 5), (5, 6, 7), ..., (8, 7, 7), (9, 8, 9), ...].`

Description:
(1) In the above example, there are three lists `a`, `b`, `c` having integer elements and the output is another list `d` of tuples.

(2) The tuples in `d` have elements belonging to (`a` and `b` and `c`) or (`a` and `b`) or (`b` and `c`) such that difference between elements within any tuple is not greater than 1.

(3) Problem: How to find the complete list `d` where we take any element from any input list and find the difference less than or equal to 1. Generalize to more than just three input list: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, ... and each one is having ~ 1000 elements. I also need to retrieve the indices relative to the input lists/ arrays that form the tuples.

(4) Clarification: (a) All such tuples which contain entries not differing by more than 1 are allowed.
(b) Tuples must have elements that are close to at least one other element by not more than 1.
(c) Entries within a tuple must belong to different input arrays/ lists.

Let me know if there are further clarifications needed!

Comment: Do you have your own solution? Any code that we could use to print out the full expected output?

Comment: No, please let me know which part will be difficult to understand/ inconsistent

Comment: There can be some solution to this by using iterations but I am trying to avoid thinking about it..

Comment: With 5 lists of 1000 elements, you have up to 10**15 (1000000000000000) combinations, this seems poorly practical. What really are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The number of combinations that pass the diff<=1 test can be very small (depending upon the distribution of elements in ```a```, ```b```, ```c```, ...). Imagine that ```a = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... upto 1000 elements very sparsely sampled]``` and same for ```b = [20, 200,  1001, 20000, ...]```: only the (1000,1001) makes through.. correct? How are you ending with upto 10**15 (1000000000000000) combinations, @mozway

Comment: `1000**5` is `10**15`

Comment: Ya that I understand, it maybe heavy on memory to load/work with a large 5d structure. Any iterative method as alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sorting** to find results faster than a naive brute-force. That being said, this assumes the number of output tuple is reasonably small. Otherwise, there is no way to find a solution in a reasonable time (eg. several months). As @mosway pointed out in the comments, the number of combinations can be **insanely huge** since the complexity is `O(N ** M)` (ie. *exponential*) where `N` is the number of list and `M` is the length of the lists.

The idea is to use `np.unique` on all lists so to get many sorted arrays with unique items. Then, you can iterate over the first array, and for each number (in the first array), find the range of values in the second one fitting in `[n-1;n+1]` using a `np.searchsorted`. You can then iterate over the filtered values of the second array and **recursively** do that on other array.

Note that regarding which array is chosen first, the method can be significantly faster. Thus, a good **heuristic** could be to select an array containing values very distant from others. Computing a distance matrix with all the values of all array and selecting the one having the biggest average distance should help.

Note also that using Numba should significantly speed up the recursive calls.

Comment: This sorting hint helped solve the issue I was working on, thank you!
I needed to check each permutation of a length 3 tuple (like (5,4,3)) and check that the following conditions were all met: at least one number >=6, one number >=4, and one number >= 1. Sorted the tuples as they came in made it a lot easier.